# Bash Shell Loop Over Set of Folders

Tags: unix

I have a list of folders. Each folder names for example:

- pippo1 containing the file pippo1.txt,
- pippo2 containing the file pippo2.txt,
- pippo3 containing the file pippo3.txt etc.

I would like to go in the first folder, remove the number from the filename pippo1.txt and then exit, go in the second folder called pippo2 containing the file pippo2.txt, remove 2 from the file name etc etc. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work! the code is:

```
for i in *
do
    cd $i
    ls *.txt | sed -e "s/[0-9]//g"
    cd ..
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A couple of questions. 1) Does each folder only have 1 text file in it? 2) You do realize that `sed` doesn't actually rename the file right? You need to use `mv` for that.

Comment: Please be more specific. Is this `bash` or `sh` and what flavor of unix/linux is this?

Comment: Yes! Each folder has 1 .txt file in. I have totally 14.669 folders

Comment: I'm using bash on Mac os x 10.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirements are just that simple, then you can do this with only bash substitution:

```
for file in `find . -name 'pippo*.txt'`; do
    mv $file ${file/[0-9].txt/.txt}
done
```

However, this will fail on more than single digits in the filename, e.g. `pippo999/pippo999.txt`. This can be addressed by setting the `extglob` option:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in `find . -name 'pippo*.txt'`; do
    mv $file ${file/+([0-9]).txt/.txt}
done
```

The `+(...)` construct in bash file globbing is only available when `extglob` is set.

Instead of traversing the directory tree with a loop and `cd`, this uses `find` to get a list of all the relevant files, then loops over that list of filenames, which will be of the form: `./pippoN/pippoN.txt`. The rename uses bash [parameter replacement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to get the modified file name. See also [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion).

Note that spaces in file or directory names **will break this approach**, beginning with the use of `find`: a path that includes spaces will be split up into multiple tokens around the spaces with each token being a separate result in the list iterator. So if you need to anticipate space characters in the paths then this becomes a bit more complicated:

```
shopt -s extglob
IFS=$'\n'
for file in `find . -name 'pippo*.txt'`; do
    mv "$file" "${file/+([0-9]).txt/.txt}"
done
```

Here we've quoted the filenames for the `mv` command, which will handle spaces correctly, and we've changed the field separator `IFS` so that bash won't recognize whitespace as a word boundary. This will fix up the problem with `find` in the loop iterator. Now spaces in the path will be handled correctly, so that e.g. `./pippo 9/pippo9.txt` will also be renamed to: `./pippo 9/pippo.txt`.

Comment: You should probably include quotes around variable names in the `mv` command to avoid problems with spaces (etc) in file names.  However, the use of the output from `find` also means there are problems if file names contain spaces.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ah good point I'd meant to include that and hadn't considered the problem with spaces in the find results. I'll add a blurb about this breaking with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

When switching directories, it is best and cleanest to invoke a sub-shell.

When renaming files, it is usually best to use the local `rename` command, or obtain one.  The trouble is that there are several 'standard' `rename` commands, and the more widely distributed one is far less powerful than the Perl-based one.  This approach avoids `rename`, but isn't completely desirable:

```
for dir in *
do
    (
    cd "$dir"
    for file in *[0-9].txt
    do
        mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed 's/[0-9]\.txt$/.txt/')
    done
    )
done
```

The Perl-based `rename` takes a regex as the first argument and applies it to the file names:

```
for dir in *
do
    (
    cd "$dir"
    rename 's/\d\.txt$/.txt/' *[0-9].txt
    )
done
```

This is more reliable.